# Turn Off SCSS Auto-Completion

Tags: sass, sublimetext2

I want SCSS syntax highlighting but with normal Sublime Text 2 completion rules. I.e. Sublime only auto-completes things I've already typed.

Annoyingly, not only does the [SCSS plug-in](https://github.com/MarioRicalde/SCSS.tmbundle) auto-complete to things I *haven't* typed, it doesn't auto-complete to things I *have* typed.

As an example, you can see it excluding the previously typed `include` from the auto-completion list:

[image: where is include?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by removing `scss_completions.py` and `scss_completions.pyc` from the SCSS package folder.